# Loading a new video in the player

Tags: youtube-api

I can't get the code below to work. I'm placing a player on the page and loading it with a video. This works as expected. Then I have a number of thumbnails of other videos I want to play when the user clicks on one of them (only two shown here). This part does not work. I get an error message on the console saying that ytplayer.loadvideobyID isn't a function. I'm testing this on Firefox 26.0.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table width="900" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <tbody>       
<tr>
  <td>      
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>
  <td>   
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td>      
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ytplayer.loadVideoById('tCnEH8MRrjE',0);"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/tCnEH8MRrjE/hqdefault.jpg" width="176" height="132"></a>     
  </td>   
</tr>   
<tr>
       <td>     
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ytplayer.loadVideoById('lqdFrGFo6SQ',0);"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/lqdFrGFo6SQ/hqdefault.jpg" width="176" height="132"></a>    
   </td>   
</tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
     // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
      // YouTube player after the API code downloads.

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() 
      {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', 
        {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'tCnEH8MRrjE',
        });
      }  

     // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
     var tag = document.createElement('script');
     tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
     var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the ID of the HTML element (`"ytplayer"`) with the name of the Javascript variable (`player`). Change `ytplayer.loadVideoById(...)` to `player.loadVideoById(...)`.

Alternatively, you can just use the same symbol (either `player` or `ytplayer`) for all of them...